# Pseudo element alignment different in FFox and Chrome

Tags: css, alignment, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a speech bubble just using CSS by using pseudo elements ::before and ::after. It looks fine to me in Chrome but the outline of the triangle looks messed up in Firefox. Does anyone know what causes this and if I can fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/K3YSy/5/

I'm using FF 9.0.1 and Chrome 16. In firefox I get odd artifacts around the triangle that don't appear in Chrome or IE9 for that matter

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me in Firefox 3.6.15 on Windows 7. In fact, aside from the lack of rounded corners it looks better than Chrome.

Comment: The fiddle you posted looks identical to me when I open it in Firefox and Chrome. Could you post more details about what you're seeing, and maybe about what version of Firefox you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those rendering artifacts around the edge of the triangle are something I've run into on Firefox when you set some borders to transparent and others to another color. It doesn't seem to be able to properly display the boundary between the colored border and the transparent ones. Unfortunately, the only way I have ever found to fix it is to set all four of them to a color, but unfortunately that won't work for you in this case.

Comment: That's annoying. Even IE9 renders it correctly, I swear this was working in FF8.

Comment: I'll save myself some trouble and use an image

Comment: After some reading I found that the issue is caused by firefox anti aliasing. It appears that the value `transparent` is equivalent to `rgba(0,0,0,0)` (transparent black). Replacing `transparent` with `rgba(255,255,255,0)` fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add -moz-border-radius: 15px; to the #bubble container for firefox to render it.

http://jsfiddle.net/K3YSy/13/